# Codeigniter get all field information

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am writing a script to check if a client's database is up to date according to a master database, but the

```
$this -> db-> field_data($a_table)
```

function does not return all the field details.

I need details like AUTO INCREMENT (under Extra in PhpMyAdmin), ASSIGNED ZEROFILL (under Attributes) and all other information like where the auto_increment starts

I could not find any other way of getting these info, so if it is not possible, then it is fine, but would be great if anybody knows how to get these.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

use below way

```
$this->db->list_fields('table')
```

or

```
$fields = $this->db->field_data('table-name');

foreach ($fields as $field)
{
   echo $field->name;        // name
   echo $field->type;        // type
   echo $field->max_length;  // maxlength
   echo $field->primary_key; // primary key
}
```

and autoincrement

```
$next = $this->db->query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table-name'");
$next = $next->row(0);
$next->Auto_increment;
echo $next->Auto_increment;
```